# wampserver not showing footer and header or CSS

Tags: php, localhost

I am using wampserve to view my site on a local server.

I can see the text but none of the CSS/Less is being applied and my header and footer are not visible. I get the message

```
Warning: include(C:/wamp64/www//Includes/Header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp64\www\flying-squid\html\index.php on line 5
```

and

```
Warning: include(): Failed opening 'C:/wamp64/www//Includes/Header.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp64\www\flying-squid\html\index.php on line 5
```

for both my header and footer.

I have looked at so many other questions on this topic here and have tried all steps to no avail.

Here is my php code in my index.php file

```
<?php 
$pagetitle      =   "About";
$description    =   "";
$keywords       =   "";
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/Includes/Header.php");
```

?>

I have tried header/includes being in lowercase and as it is above but nothing works.

I am very new to this and don't really know much php yet, I have been learning css, html, less and javascript.

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."Includes/Header.php"); Try this. Or better use `__DIR__.'/../relativepath'`

Comment: I have this (see above code) but it doesn't work

Comment: No, you have a slash before include, i dont have it, see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good practice to help prevent this problem is to maintain naming conventions, such as directories and files standardly being entirely lowercase. That way you will not get hung up on wondering if character case is part of your issue.

Depending on the structure of your site you may want to try multiple approaches:

- `__DIR__./../..`
- `($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."Includes/Header.php")`
- `include('../Includes/Header.php')`

---

As you're admittedly new to PHP, I wanted to let you know that this is common when using `include()`, `include_once()`, `require()` and `require_once()` inclusions (among other file manipulation functions). Any and all of these functions throw this `Warning` if it cannot locate the file specified exactly at the path it was given.

Comment: Try using `phpinfo();` and then search for a key named `DOCUMENT_ROOT` under "Apache Environment" and let me know what it is. Notice that your `Warning` shows two `/` before `Includes` which leads me to believe the problem is within the `php.ini` file (if you're positive the file you're trying to `include()` exists), but I'm not sure with a prepackaged installation such as "wampserve".

Comment: While that is a good lesson in `php.ini` editing, try simply removing the `/` before `Includes` so that it reads `include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."Includes/Header.php");`

Comment: Hey, Thanks and yes the file exists, I have checked it and its all there. when i use phpinfo() I get C:/wamp64/www/

Comment: It currently is just Includes/Header.php and not working. I am using less, nodejs and grunt if that helps

Comment: The `DOCUMENT_ROOT` key does not typically end in `/` on a standard installation, though it appears it does in a "wampserve" environment. Either open `php.ini` within your PHP installation folder, search for `DOCUMENT_ROOT` and remove the trailing `/`, or get in the habit of not using the first `/` in your inclusion pathing whenever on this server as I mentioned in a prior comment. You will have to restart Apache for this to take effect.

Comment: Warning: include(): Failed opening 'C:/wamp64/www/Includes/Header.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp64\www\flying-squid\html\index.php on line 5

Comment: Go to your browser and try to browse to: `//localhost/Includes/Header.php'` and tell me if it finds the file.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help, it says this Notice: Undefined variable: description in C:\wamp64\www\flying-squid\html\Includes\Header.php on line 16 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0013236616{main}( )...\Header.php:0 "> ( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: keywords in C:\wamp64\www\flying-squid\html\Includes\Header.php on line 18 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0013236616{main}( )...\Header.php:0 ">

Comment: After further looking at the errors you commented on you'll notice it has your `DOCUMENT_ROOT` of `C:\wamp64\www` listed, but followed by `\flying-squid\html\...` which means the `include()` path may actually need to be `flying-squid/html/Includes/Header.php` (without or without the leading `/`).

Comment: Thanks I will try that now!

Comment: This means that any includes you may have, including in other languages such as CSS and JavaScript, will need the `flying-squid/html` pathing prefix, so double check that your CSS include within the HTML has the right path. Unfortunately anything outside of that would be better suited in the proper StackOverflow tags as it will require seeing the code.

Comment: Great thanks so much for your help, as least we fixed something :)

Comment: Glad I could help; best of luck!